# How to upload/access database online

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms

I have a small POS system in my store, and i want to create a new app and install it to my laptop, the problem is how to access the database even im far away. Where can i upload my database to be accesible through internet?

I am using MySQL and C# windows form application.

Comment: You can achieve this by purchasing / setting up a internet accessible server and running the database on there.  

Amazon AWS / Microsoft Azure are a couple of examples.

Then point your application to the database on the server using the IP address or if you've setup a domain name you can use that instead of the IP.

Comment: On a cloud provider? On a dedicated server? On a VPS? on your own machine with the relevant firewall ports open and forwarded? Did you so any research?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem sounds more around system architecture than actual code based problem.

If you want to access your POS database when you are out and about, then there are several solutions.

1. You can use a VPN / Tunnel to securely access your internal network even when you are physically outside of your building. This can be difficult to setup however.

   2. You can move your POS Database to the cloud - Using a service such as AWS, Azure etc to make your Database reachable to the world at large. This does however pose a security risk, as in order for you to access the database, you will need to expose the DB port to the world at large, and then people can start to try and brute force the passwords.

The solution I would actually recommend, is that you do put your DB in the cloud but make sure the DB port is closed to the outside world. If you wish to get data from the database, you do so via an MVC Web Service application hosted on the same machine as the Database.
This way you can control access to the database with custom application logic.

So lets imagine how this would work once implemented

You send a JSON Rest request to the endpoint:

```
https://example.com/POSAPI/GetTransactions

{
   "SessionToken:"j9hf928hjo2ij09kr8023",
   "FromDate":"20-02-2018",
   "ToDate":"29-02-2018",
   "AmountToReturn":"45"
}
```

It would then authenticate based on the SessionToken you provide - this value will authenticate the user for for 5 minutes etc

The response from the endpoint would then send back the 45 transactions that occurred between FromDate and ToDate.

Most people will agree that your C# Application should not be accessing a database directly if it is a client based application.
C# Applications can be disassembled easily to get stored credentials.
It is best to keep as much of your database access restricted to a web based API and control the flow and access of data via that API.

I do appreciate that this may be a learning curve and may not be the simplest solution you were hoping for, but most people will agree that direct database access is typically a security risk and the use of an API to interact with the database is generally a best practice.

Comment: If i uploaded my database in azure, will there be changes in my queries on reading and writing data?

Comment: Azure and EC2 may result in changes to your connection string, but the queries themselves should remain the same.